# The Container i am using is taking the full width of screen

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a container in a list view builder, but for some reason no matter what i set the width as, it takes the full width of the screen. i really do not know what is wrong right now. here is the code

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _productStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }

        if (!snapshot.hasData){
          return Container();
        }

        return ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return Container(
              height:300,
              width: 40,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 120,
                    width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.8,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      image: snapshot.data!.docs[index]['itemImage'] != null ?
                      DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage(snapshot.data!.docs[index]['itemImage'])):
                          DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage(snapshot.data!.docs[index]['itemImageList'][1]))
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
            }
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

the outer container takes the full width of the screen and the child container does not take enough width no matter what i set the width to. perhaps

Answer (score 2):

I think you can Wrap your ListViewBuilder with a SizedBox to specify the width. You can also add a Center Widget to center your ListView.

```
Center(
  child: SizedBox(
    width: 40,
    child: ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ...
      },
    ),
  ),
),
```